# Check string indentation?

Tags: python, indentation, analysis, lint

I'm building an analyzer for a series of strings.
I need to check how much each line is indented (either by tabs or by spaces).

Each line is just a string in a text editor.
How do I check by how much a string is indented?

Or rather, maybe I could check how much whitespace or \t are before a string, but I'm unsure of how.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378962/returning-the-lowest-index-for-the-first-non-whitespace-character-in-a-string-in

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: you know how space is represented? a tab? count the occurences and you are good to go, no?

Comment: Will tabs and spaces ever be mixed at the start of a line?

Comment: @jbowes , sorry, I was going to post what I had tried but was bombarded with issues at work just then.

I tried pretty much what Gizmo suggested below which was to subtract lengths.

Tabs and spaces might be mixed but I believe all the programs at work are 4 space tabs, so if I can figure out whats a tab and whats a space I can get a good indentation value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grab a line's whitespace/indention with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268532/grab-a-lines-whitespace-indention-with-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To count the number of spaces at the beginning of a string you could do a comparison between the left stripped (whitespace removed) string and the original:

```
a = "    indented string"
leading_spaces = len(a) - len(a.lstrip())
print(leading_spaces) 
# >>> 4
```

Tab indent is context specific... it changes based on the settings of whatever program is displaying the tab characters. This approach will only tell you the total number of whitespace characters (each tab will be considered one character).

Or to demonstrate:

```
a = "\t\tindented string"
leading_spaces = len(a) - len(a.lstrip())
print(leading_spaces)
# >>> 2
```

EDIT:

If you want to do this to a whole file you might want to try

```
with open("myfile.txt") as afile:
    line_lengths = [len(line) - len(line.lstrip()) for line in afile]
```

Comment: That's sort of the solution I got but then I'm not confused as to how to tell what is a tab and what is a space?

Comment: @DhruvGovil You're correct... this won't tell you if it's a tab or a space. If you want to know how many spaces I'd use `line.expandtab(4)` as mentioned by martineau to expand the tabs out to spaces. This will tell you the absolute number of spaces. Zeroing the line lengths for lines without text is also a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if you know the whitespace exists on the front of the string.  If the end of the string happens to also have whitespace, your result will be skewed.

Answer (score 9):

I think Gizmo's basic idea is good, and it's relatively easy to extend it to handle any mixture of leading tabs and spaces by using a string object's `expandtabs()` method:

```
def indentation(s, tabsize=4):
    sx = s.expandtabs(tabsize)
    return 0 if sx.isspace() else len(sx) - len(sx.lstrip())

print indentation("  tindented string")
print indentation("\t\tindented string")
print indentation("  \t  \tindented string")
```

The last two print statements will output the same value.

Edit: I modified it to check and return 0 if a line of all tabs and spaces is encountered.

Comment: Thanks, missed this earlier but that expandtabs is certainly handy.

Answer (score 2):

The len() method will count tab (\t) as one. In some case, it will not behave expectedly. So my way is to use re.sub and then count the space(s).

```
indent_count = re.sub(r'^([\s]*)[\s]+.*$', r'\g<1>', line).count(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_indentation(line) : 
    count = 0 
    try : 
        while (line[count] == "\t") : 
            count += 1 
        return count
    except : 
        return count
```

Comment: Why do we need a except statement here? Any specific reason?

Comment: when count reach the max counter( len - ) it wil check line[len] which is exception out of range if you do want to remove it add in while if counter = len(line) - 1 : break