# Using regular expression to count the number of spaces at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, string, whitespace, space

How can I use regex to count the number of spaces beginning of the string. For example:

```
string = ' area border router'
```

count_space variable would return me a value of 1 since there is 1 whitespace at the beginning of the string. If my string is:

```
string = '  router ospf 1'
```

count_space variable would return me a value of 2 since there is 2 whitespace at the beginning of the string. And so on....

I thing the expression would be something like RE = '^\s' ? But not sure how to formulate it.

Comment: Nevermind! I found someone that has the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241399/check-string-indentation

Comment: Another Possible duplicate: [Returning the lowest index for the first non whitespace character in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378962/returning-the-lowest-index-for-the-first-non-whitespace-character-in-a-string-in)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, you can just do this:

```
s = ' area border router'
print(len(s)-len(s.lstrip()))
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: I can't accept.. I don't have enough votes... Your solution definitely works! Thank you so much.. You answered quicker than I posted the link..

Comment: This does not work when a string also contains other whitespace characters other than space.