# set tabstop=4 put only one space at the beginning

Tags: vim, terminal, vi

In my .vimrc file, i wrote down `set tabstop=4` in order to have a tab equal to 4 spaces, but when I use tab in a C file, only one space is written. I have to put another tab to write 4 spaces.

How can I solve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A tabstop doesn't mean that every tab is equivalent to 4 spaces. It means that a tab character will represent 1-4 spaces so that the *next* character appears in a column that's a multiple of 4.

Comment: Oh okay thanks I get it. But what settings should I put to only type one tab and have 4 spaces ?

Comment: @zelph14 https://stackoverflow.com/q/68900259/7976758

Comment: @phd unfortunately I still have to type twice on tab with this

Comment: It sounds like you don't want tab stops: you want to remap the tab key to enter 4 spaces instead.

Comment: I've not tested this. Put in your .vimrc `set ts=4 sw=4`  source: https://superuser.com/questions/505937/how-to-set-tab-to-4-spaces-in-vim/505948

Comment: Is there more information available on this @chepner ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have in my .vimrc file:
When in insert mode, I press tab and four spaces appear in my file.

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```