# Python: Keeping whitespace at the beginning of a string

Tags: python, string

I Have a string that looks like this:

```
old_string = '      Some_text'
```

And I want to write a new string, but I would like to keep the same white-space at the beginning. 
Is there a way in Python that I can keep this white-space?
The white-space could contain spaces or tabs, but the exact number of tabs or spaces is unknown.
I think this could be done using regex but I'm not sure if there is a way. And since the text in the string is not always the same I can't use

```
new_string = old_string.replace('Some_text','new_text')
```

any thoughts would be more than welcome.

Comment: @Rachitkapadia I don't think it is a duplicate. The OP wants a new string with the exact same leading whitespace as the old one (be it spaces or tabs). It's not the same as counting.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2268532/2301450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
new_string = old_string[:-len(old_string.lstrip())] + 'new text'
```

Or if you prefer `str.format`:

```
new_string = '{}new text'.format(old_string[:-len(old_string.lstrip())])
```

Answer (score 0):

Count how many characters get removed when you use `lstrip`;

```
str = '      Some_text'
whitespace = len(str) - len(str.lstrip())
print(whitespace)
```

Outputs;

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to get the leading whitespace characters:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> old_string = '      Some_text'
>>> whitespace = list(takewhile(str.isspace, old_string))
>>> "".join(whitespace)
'      ' 
>>> len(whitespace) 
6
```

To get the rest of the string you could use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> "".join(dropwhile(str.isspace, old_string))      
'Some_text'
```

Comment: You could close the question as duplicate instead of providing a nearly identical answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2268627/2301450